# How to deal with async functions in express js router

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, async-await

There is a lint error, that basically says that we cannot return Promises in places where a void is expected, the message is clear, but how to fix it without lying to the linter by using any or (as any), both functions [validateJWT, getUser] are async functions It looks pretty basic, but I do not know how to fix it in an easy way. thanks!

```html
    
        import { Router } from 'express';
        import { getUser } from '../controllers/userController';
        import { validateJWT } from '../middlewares/validateJWT';
    
        const router = Router();
    
        router.get('/user', validateJWT, getUser);
    
        export default router;
    
    
    
    
    
        const getUser = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: 
          NextFunction): Promise<any> => {
        try {
            const { id } = req.params;
            if (!id) {
                let response = formatErrorResponse({ error: true, statusCode: 400, errorMessage: 'Missing id in params' });
                return res.status(400).json(response);
            }
            let user = await User.findById({_id: id});
            let objRes = { error: false, statusCode: 200, message: 'User was found', data: user };
            return res.status(200).json(objRes);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error in controller /user', error)
            next(error);
        }
    }
    
    export {
        getUser
    }
    
    
    
    
         const validateJWT = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<any> => {
        const token = req.header('x-token');
        console.log(req)
        if (!token) {
            const err = formatErrorResponse({ error: true, statusCode: 401, errorMessage: 'Missing header x-token' });
            return res.status(401).json(err);
        } 
        try { 
            await verifyToken(token);
            next(); 
        } catch (error) {
            const err = formatErrorResponse({error: true, statusCode: 401, errorMessage: 'Invalid token, athorization denied', errorContent: error});
            return res.status(400).json(err);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of the functions `getUser` and `validateJWT`? The answers below assume you haven't written them as middleware and route but as promise-returning functions instead. I'm not sure if this is the case, if so the answers below make sense. If on the other hand you've written them as regular middleware and route but with just the `async` keyword in front of them then the answers below make little sense.

Comment: @slebetman, my answers assumes that validatJWT is a middleware, hence `router.use(validateJWT)`. this is because its imported from ../midlewares. The other one is imported from controllers, so the assumption is that this isnt a middleware.

Comment: @TheFool That was not how you originally wrote it. Anyway, `router.get('/user', validateJWT, getUser)` is perfectly correct code for how to use a middleware. You could either install the middleware at the router level using `.use()` or at the endpoint itself the way the OP did. If you did not know it before then consider it something new you've learned.

Comment: @slebetman, I didn't know, I don't actually use express because it's from the stone age. I still think the crux of my answer holds true. Express doesn't allow async handlers. Hence they have the wrap function in their docs. It's just weird that they have async Middleware as per docs, for some reason. Why can Middleware be async but handlers not?

Comment: @slebetman, my answer was using this as middleware all along, though. You can see it in the edit history. It's just that at some point I saw in the docs that they were using async middleware, so I have removed the wrapper code.

Comment: @slebetman I updated the code

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like the below.

```js
router.use(validateJWT)

router.get('/users/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    getUser(req.params.id)
        .then(res.json)
        .catch(next);
});
```

In the docs, I could see an async middleware example http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html#mw-fig.

I could not find an async handler example. I recall that back in the day, express didn't support async handler. Hence, I used .then inside the handler. You need to double-check if you can use them nowadays.

In the express docs is also an [example](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#use-promises) like the below. It makes working with async handler more convenient in some regard. As you can wrap all your async handler with this wrapper.

```
const wrap = fn => (...args) => fn(...args).catch(args[2]);

router.get('/users/:id', wrap(getUser));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your implementation of the function to work like this:

```
router.get('/user', (req, res) => {
  validateJWT(req, res);
  getUser(req, res);
});
```

Since `express.Router` instances expect the `route` as a `string` for the first parameter which you have as `"/user"`. And a second parameter which is a callback.

Inside that callback you can call your functions.

Assuming you need `validateJWT` to finish running before `getUser` you could do something like this:

```
validateJWT(...).then((...) => getUser(...));
```